# get size of current assembly in memory

Tags: c#, memory, size

How can i get the size of the current assembly in memory?

This does the trick for once:

```
while (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 < 1 gigabyte)
```

But its not changing the value even though the assembly is growing in memory.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've never seen the literal "1 gigabyte" in C#.  Are you sure this is real code?

Comment: What does the notion of `size of the current assembly in memory` means? Never heard of anything like that. What is a size of an assembly in memory and more importantly why do you expect that this value would change? In .NET the CLR allocates instances of objects. It's those instances that consume memory. Is it what you are asking about? If yes, let's consider the following scenario: the assembly calls into an unmanaged C++ component that allocates memory -> do you want to account for this memory as well?

Comment: Do you mean the current memory usage of an assembly?

Comment: Yes, i mean the current memory usage of the application/assembly im building. @Adam, 1 gigabyte isn't C# code, but would you have known out of your head if i have put it in bytes? To the point: i was just making it easier to read.

Comment: @Yustme, OK, so what about the unmanaged memory question I've asked in my comment? Are you interested in that as well? Because even with very simple code that reads from a file, behind the scenes you are allocating an unmanaged handle.

Comment: What do you mean with unmanaged? Can't this be done with C# alone? An app that checks how much memory its taking every time a call some method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `PrivateMemorySize64`, use `WorkingSet64` or `VirtualMemorySize64`, depending on whether you mean 'currently in memory' or 'total memory'.

`WorkingSet64` gives you the number of bytes that are currently in the machine's RAM.

`VirtualMemorySize64` gives you the number of bytes that are in the process's address space. This includes bytes currently in RAM as well as bytes swapped out to disk.